# jQuery validation plugin on contact form

Tags: jquery, html, validation, plugins

I am using the [jQuery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) and I have tried it on few login forms and it works fine.

But now I need to do it on a contact form and it just doesn't work

Here's the code

```
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js">
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".contacts-form").validate({
            rules: {
                name: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                message: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                name: "Please enter a name",
                email: {
                    required: "Please enter email",
                    email: "Invalid Email"
                },
                message: "Please enter message"
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

here's html

```
<form method="POST" action="contacts-back-end.php" class="contacts-form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name*" name="name">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email*" name="email">
                <input type="text" placeholder="About" name="about">
                <textarea placeholder="Message*" rows="10" name="message"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" class="button">
            </form>
```

Comment: What is not working? Any error in console?

Comment: Everything is working fine. Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chiragraninga/b3upa3cs/)